# Font package needed for PDF built using TEX?

Tags: fonts, pdf, embedding

This question might sound stupid (I am not a CS major). I built my grad school application resume using Latex (based on a CS grad suggestion :) ) and successfully generated the required PDF. I understand that Computer modern font is the default font but I used the **\usepackage[font]** option to use *New Century Schoolbook* with a little help from here: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/

It says there that to use New Century Schoolbook , you need to have it in your system. So my question is this:  **if someone reads my PDF in a system that doesnt support New Century Schoolbook, will they face issues reading it?**

Or is the fact that ' you need to have font installed in your system' ( as given in the site above) apply only to TEX file and not the PDF file?
Or do I have it wrong and New Century Schoolbook is as common as Times New Roman or Arial?

Comment: when you produce a PDF using *TeX, the fonts will be embedded into that PDF (unless you tell TeX to do otherwise, which is **not** recommended). So whoever receives your PDF doesn't need to have specific fonts installed on their machine ...does that answer your question?

Comment: Moreover, you can check for font embedding by either uninstalling the font and opening the .pdf, or just opening the .pdf and checking the document properties in a .pdf reader which supports showing such information.

Comment: @NilsL That's what I thought originally. Then I remembered that sometimes a downloaded PDF file asks you to install say, like a Chinese font, to render the PDF properly. If it were embedded , why would it ask me to install a font pack. ( I've seen examples of technical reports and data sheets)

Comment: @pjamu: That's because fonts for [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK) are typically _very_ large and historically not embedded.

Comment: @MartinSchröder  So I can go ahead with new century schoolbook font since it gets embedded? Btw, I used **sharelatex.com** to generate the pdf. I hope that site uses appropriate tools to _generate such an embedded pdf_.

Comment: @pjamu: Yes. Typically fonts are embedded.

Comment: There are some caveats to this. I haven't checked recently but certainly a few years ago, the "standard" postscript fonts (those traditionally installed in laser printers themselves) were not embedded by default but other fonts were embedded as subsets by default. Subsets is fine - it just means the PDF includes only those characters required to display the PDF. So it is definitely worth checking the PDF as suggested. On GNU/Linux, you can also do this with tools such as pdffonts but opening the PDF and viewing the properties works too.

Comment: @cfr Too lazy to read all the comments now, wanna answer? Or take other action?

Comment: @Johannes_B Will this do?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have altered the default configuration, the major TeX distributions in their current forms ***embed*** most fonts by default. This means that you only need to worry about the availability of fonts on readers' systems if you are typesetting certain non-Latin scripts (e.g. Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.).

Older installations of TeX defaulted to not embedding the most common postscript fonts, but embedding all others.

Regardless, I would always recommend checking that fonts are embedded before submitting or sending an important document. There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to use a PDF viewer and look for the document's `Properties`. This should include information on `Fonts`.

For example, here's Okular's display for a simple sample document:

[image: fonts]

This is OK as all fonts are listed as 'Embedded'. (Subsets are fine.)

The other option is to use a command line or other utility such as `pdffonts` which produces the following for the same example:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
VJGNPX+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
OTQOSA+CMBX12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
ZQOAXT+CMTI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
```

The crucial column here is headed `emb` and the important thing is that all entries in this column are `yes`.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :-)